# actions on google - authentication token requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are attempting to create a google home action with OAuth2.0 using authentication code (rather than implicit code). Note we had it working previously with implicit code, but due to requirements of the project need to switch over).

Our token endpoint (using AWS Cognito service) requires:

"If the client was issued a secret, the client must pass its client_id and client_secret in the authorization header through Basic HTTP authorization. The secret is Basic Base64Encode(client_id:client_secret)."

However, this is not how google authentication will send the data to the token. We can force this in postman and it does work, but will not link the user using the actions on google simulator.

Is there a way to configure our project to pass the basic-encoded data? Has anyone else gotten this working using AWS cognito?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I work at Cognito. Yes, we do have this requirement that "If the client was issued a secret, the client must pass its client_id and client_secret in the authorization header through Basic HTTP authorization. The secret is Basic Base64Encode(client_id:client_secret)." So you need to process the data to this format and put it in the authorization header and the token endpoint will work. I am not familiar with the Google simulator part and I think you need to do the generating authorization header part in your app code.